# Solo Closing a Question from First Question Review Queue caused an Error

Tags: bug, first-questions

I was working through my First questions review queue and I came across the question [Writing to csv makes column without being written](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69156378/15497888)/[Link to the question in Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29807815).

This question has an accepted answer as well as the content to establish that the index column of a pandas DataFrame is being included in an output csv and this is not the desired behaviour.

I went to close it from within the review queue as a duplicate of [Pandas to_csv call is prepending a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30605909/15497888), and because I have a `pandas` gold tag badge I can solo close it as a duplicate.

The close interface froze for a bit, then I got an quick message that an error occurred, then the item became unreviewable without allowing me to complete the review:

[image: You are not able to review this item]

Comment: That’s interesting. This is really similar to [a bug report I filed on the original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369117#369117). That bug was subsequently fixed—but, it seems, only for collaborative deletes, not unilateral deletes.

Comment: This could also be an issue if there are two pending close votes (four on other sites which require five votes to close) and a reviewer casts the final vote to close.